# break endless while loop (containing phpmailer)

Tags: php, loops, email

I accidentally changed the line:

```
$timenow = $timenow + 1;
```

to

```
//$timenow = $timenow + 1;
```

So I made an endless loop.

Why does my extra security(the `break` function) not work?
I keep getting mails. When I place `echo "1";` in the while loop, it stops after 100 seconds. But the while doesn't stop when I have the phpmailer placed in the loop.

My code:

```
<?php
      $times = 20;
      $timenow = 0;
      $startTime = time();
      $timeout = 100;   //timeout in seconds
      while($timenow < $times){
         if(time() > $startTime + $timeout) {
             break;
         }
            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            //Set who the message is to be sent from
            $mail->setFrom('noreply@offertes-krijgen.nl', 'noreply');
            //Set an alternative reply-to address
            $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@offertes-krijgen.nl', 'noreply');
            //Set who the message is to be sent to
            $mail->addAddress($somevar, $somevar2);
            //Set the subject line
            $mail->Subject = 'subject';
            //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
            //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
            $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
            //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the mail';
            //Attach an image file
            $mail->addAttachment('');
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/phpmailer_mini.png', 'logo');

            //send the message, check for errors
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                $mailerror = 1;
            }
       $timenow = $timenow + 1;
        }
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Stops after 20 times for me.](https://3v4l.org/sYM7R) Maybe your actual code is different than posted here.

Comment: Yes, but if you make the line $timenow = $timenow + 1; a comment instead of a code line it is an endless loop.

Comment: [No, it's not.](https://3v4l.org/KAXui) Maybe it *feels* like it because you have a 100 second timeout.

Comment: That's what I thought to. But it didn't stop after 100 seconds. The page did appear after 100 seconds but de mailer continued mailing.

Comment: In default configuration, which your example seems to use, PHPMailer hands the message off to system `sendmail`. That in turn queues the message locally, use the `mailq` command to see. Perhaps it appeared to "continue to send" because they were queued in the OS even after the script stopped.

Comment: Thanks, I thought in the same direction. To bad I don't have permission to everything on the server. So I can't use the command line